# Facebook Ajax Search

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to place a new manager to my page using jQuery,

[image: Facebook Search Window]

How can I make it by using jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)! In order to improve your experience on the site, you should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. You must provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), sharing us what you've tried and or at least where you're stuck, since this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why and how you would want to use jQuery, but afaik there is no way to automate assigning page roles. You can only read them with the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/roles/

Rule of thumb: If there is no way with the API, then it´s not allowed.

Comment: I want to make a macro that using jQuery. There is no connection to the Graph API

Comment: scraping facebook is not allowed, i´m afraid.

Comment: Why its not allowed?